# Posting a form dependant on a javascript function returning true

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've got a form where a user will generate a lower level of accounts to the system. I need the form to validate that the user hasn't used the same username twice. How do I set it so that the form will only post to the next page to post to the database if the javascript returns true? At the moment it will flag the duplication but carry-on to post to the next page and to the database

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function validate() {
        if(document.myForm.namea == document.myForm.name2 || 
           document.myForm.namea == document.myForm.name3 ||
           document.myForm.namea == document.myForm.name4 ||
           document.myForm.namea == document.myForm.name5 ||
           document.myForm.namea == document.myForm.name6 ||
           document.myForm.namea == document.myForm.name7 || 
           document.myForm.namea == document.myForm.name8 ||
           document.myForm.namea == document.myForm.name9 ||
           document.myForm.namea == document.myForm.name10 ||
           document.myForm.namea == document.myForm.name11 ||
           document.myForm.namea == document.myForm.name12 ||
           document.myForm.namea == document.myForm.name14 ||
           document.myForm.namea == document.myForm.name15 ||
           document.myForm.namea == document.myForm.name16 ||
           document.myForm.namea == document.myForm.name17 ||
           document.myForm.namea == document.myForm.name18 ){
            alert("You have entered the same username twice");
            document.myForm.namea.focus();
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    function validator(){
        validate();
        if(validate() == true){
               document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
        }       
    }
</script>

<form action='insertgenerate.php' id="myForm" method='POST' name="myForm"   enctype='multipart/form-data'>

<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="submit" onclick="validator();" >
   Generate
</button>
```

Actual result - will flag the duplication but carry-on to post to the next page and to the database.
Expected result - flag error and stay and stay on same page without posting

Comment: Your button will automatically submit the form if you don't prevent it (because it is of type submit). One solution would be to replace onclick by onsubmit, and start your validator function with e.preventDefault() (e being passed as an argument of your validator function)

Comment: The reason why the form is submitting even though the form does not validate, is because the type attribute of the button is set to "submit". If you change the attribute to "button", then the form should not submit in case of errors

Comment: @bernardPagoga Thanks for your help - onSubmit="validator();"  

function(e){

e.preventDefault();
validate();
if(validate() == true) {

document.getElementById("myForm").submit();

}
}


Is this how your suggestion looks? This doesn't return the duplication it just posts straights to the database

Comment: @NadirLatif thanks for your help, this now just flags the duplication alert even if the duplication hasnt been flagged. Any further suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Well you can assign unique ids to each input field. It will make the validation code simpler. For example use namea,name2,name3 etc as the id. The validation code can be:

```
function validate() {
    for (count = 2; count <= 18; count++) {
        if (document.getElementById("namea").value == document.getElementById("name"+count).value) {
            alert("You have entered the same username twice");
            document.getElementById("namea").focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```